# SQL / Posgresql / Sequelize - Are there equivalent conditional operators for "some" or "every" methods?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Currently, our database queries rows from two tables.  On the backend(NodeJS), the entire data is run through few conditional statements to parse out data.  Not the most efficient since if there are thousands of rows, it's quite slow.

```
if ((data.VALIDATION_ERRORS.length) || (data.table2.items.some(i => i.VALIDATION_ERRORS) && record.items.every(i => i.VALIDATION_RESULT))) {
status = patchManagementStatuses.failed;
}
```

Hence, I wanted to see if refactoring can be done to narrow down the query.

Please see example:

```
**Table 1**

record_id |  validation_errors
----------+-------------------
   1      | [{"someError":val}]
   2      |        []
   3      |        []
   4      |        []

**Table 2**

record_id |  validation_errors  | validation_result
----------+----------------------+-------------------
   1      |        null          |       true
   2      |        null          |       true
   2      | [{"someError":val}]  |       true
   2      | [{"someError":val}]  |       true
```

```
select table1."RECORD_ID" as t1_record_id, 
table2."RECORD_ID" as t2_record_id, 
t2."VALIDATION_RESULT" , 
t2."VALIDATION_ERRORS",
t1."VALIDATION_ERRORS",
'error' as status from "table1" t1
join "table2" t2 on t2."RECORD_ID" = t1."RECORD_ID"
where t2."VALIDATION_RESULT" is true and 
t1."VALIDATION_ERRORS"::jsonb @> '[{}]'and 
t2."VALIDATION_ERRORS" is not null
group by t1."RECORD_ID" , t2."RECORD_ID"
```

I expected to get rows that met the WHERE conditional statements but I get this error:

SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "t2.VALIDATION_RESULT" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
Position: 74
Error position: line: 3 pos: 73

if i remove the group by, it returns without any errors, but that's when i need to return a single unique row of record_id using the "some" or "every" method, is it possible as a SQL query?

Much appreciated for any assistance.